# how to add MP4(proprietary codecs) support in cefpython

Tags: encryption, chromium, cefsharp, cefpython

I want to add MP4 and MP3 support in Cefpython, I read many things on the internet that add "proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome" in your GYP_DEFINES" but I want to ask that is these changes are same for cefSharp, cefPython? but after change what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

To have proprietary codecs support you need to build both CEF and cefpython/cefsharp from sources. Building CEF from sources is a long process that can take several hours at best. To build cefpython with proprietary codecs you would have to modify the automate.py tool that comes with cefpython and add the proprietary codecs variables to either GN_DEFINES or GYP_DEFINES (add to both to be sure):

```
env["GN_DEFINES"] = "use_sysroot=true use_allocator=none symbol_level=1"
```

Source line in automate.py: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/bbf3597ba47f72db66cf304ab8eb3ccfc3a7130c/tools/automate.py#L873

After that you should follow according to the [Build-instructions.md](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/docs/Build-instructions.md) document in cefpython and build CEF from sources.